# Twoport T-Network - Why does the voltage increase?

Tags: voltage

I am new to electrical engineering and currently struggling to understand following network:

[image]

Activating both current sources and using arbitrary values for the currents and for the resistors i get a higher voltage for `U_1` and `U_2` in comparison to when i only activate one current source.

It just isn't intuitive for me. I imagine to water pumps; why should one pump increase the pressure of the other pump and vice versa?

Comment: Makes sense to me... More current through R_C means more voltage across R_C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A current source has infinite internal resistance. Let's assume all resistors have the same value, 1 \$\Omega\$. Let's also assume that \$I_1=1\text{A}\$ and \$I_2\$ is either zero or equal to \$I_1\$.

a) \$I_2=0\text{A}\$ means \$R_B\$ will be in series with an infinite resitance, and both of them in parallel with \$R_C\$. The equivalent resistance will be \$R_e=1\Omega\$. The total resistance seen by \$I_1\$ will be \$R_A+R_e=2\Omega\$, thus the voltage will be \$U_1=2\Omega\cdot1\text{A}=2\text{V}\$. An alternative way of looking at this is to consider the current through \$R_B\$ as zero, and only \$1\text{A}\$ flowing through \$R_A\$ and \$R_C\$ from \$I_1\$.

b) \$I_2=1\text{A}\$ means the currents through \$R_A\$ and \$R_B\$ will be \$1\text{A}\$, for each, and for \$R_C\$ there will be \$2\text{A}\$ (one from each source). Thus the voltages across each resistors will be proportional to the currents, and each side will see a voltage of \$3\text{V}\$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!